# Formatting page number (fancyhdr?)

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, fancyhdr

Could anyone please show me how to get this page number formatting:

[image]

Comment: Is the `3` the chapter, and `11` the page number?

Comment: No, 3 is the page number, and 11 is the number of pages. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code should be well-commented I hope.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in,hmargin={1in,1.5in},headsep=0.3in,headheight=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\ooalign{%
\color{black!60!white}% background box color
\rule[0.05in]{0.8in}{1in}% background box raise, width, height
\cr
\hfil\strut\raisebox{0.25in}{% number raise
\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}% number color
\Huge% number fontsize
\thepage
\kern0.1em% distance number-bar
\rule{1pt}{1.4ex}% bar size
\kern0.15em% distance bar-totalnumber
\Large% totalnumber fontsize
\pageref{LastPage}}\hfil
}}}
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{1.2in}% protrusion 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-35]
\newpage
\lipsum[1-35]

\end{document}
```