# Box with chapter number on each even page

Tags: boxes

How can I create a thin box box with the numbering of the current chapter on (for normal text page styles)? in the **vertical middle of each even page** e.g. a thin stripe at the right end of the page like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Related: [Wrap page number in colored box in footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246766/124842) or [Formatting page number (fancyhdr?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89666/124842)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It's not too far from what I am looking for! But it's not in the vertical middle of the page (I updated my question) and I only want it on eve pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place random content on a page during the page shipout routine via [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic).

The example below inserts the chapter number (represented by `\thechapter`) vertically centred on the right side of the page. An extra conditional `\showchapterthumb<TF>` turns on the showing of the chapter number thumbs if set to `\..true`. The default is `\..false`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}

\definecolor{chapterthumbbg}{HTML}{6F7175}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \ifshowchapterthumb\ifodd\value{page}\else
      \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}{%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{\baselineskip}%
          \colorbox{chapterthumbbg}{\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}%
        }%
      }%
    \fi\fi
  }
}

\newif\ifshowchapterthumb

\sloppy% Just for this document

\begin{document}

\showchapterthumbfalse% Default

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\showchapterthumbtrue% Show chapter thumbs

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\end{document}
```

<sub><sub>Background page numbers have been added for visual purposes only.</sub></sub>

Comment: ... can we move the box slightly more to the right ... all the way to the left edge of the page? now there are a few millimeters in between :)

Comment: @Jonas: I accidentally forgot to place a specific `%` within the definition. I've corrected that in the example code above.

Comment: How can I have this on both pages? Right and left

Comment: @Jonas: Here's [some code](https://pastebin.com/6iEDw7bY) that does that. You can just update it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? It's easy with  `titleps`, which comes with `titlesec`:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}%

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
    \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \newpagestyle{mine}{%
    \widenhead[2em][0em]{0em}{0em}
    \sethead[\smash{\colorbox{SlateGrey!70}{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{5ex}\sffamily\Large\bfseries\thechapter}}][][]{}{}{}
    \setfoot{}{}{}
    }
    \pagestyle{mine}

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{introduction}
    \lipsum[1-8]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

A variant: define page style as

```
   \newpagestyle{thine}{%
    \widenhead[2em][0em]{0em}{0em}
    \sethead[\raisebox{-\dimexpr\headsep+\headheight+2ex\relax} {\colorbox{SlateGrey!70}{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{5ex}\sffamily\Large\bfseries\thechapter}}][][]{}{}{}
    \setfoot{}{}{}
    }
```

to obtain this:
[image]

*Edit*:
 I think I've understood what you want. Does this code yield what you want?

```
    \newpagestyle{midpage}{%
    \widenhead[2em][0em]{0em}{0em}
    \sethead[\raisebox{-\dimexpr\headsep+\headheight+0.5\textheight\relax}{\colorbox{SlateGrey!70}{\parbox{1.4em}{\centering\rule[-2.8ex]{0pt}{8ex}\sffamily\Large\bfseries\thechapter}}}][][]{}{}{}
    \setfoot{}{}{}
    }
    \pagestyle{midpage}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking good, thanks! I'll try it myself later on :)

Comment: Is there a way to move the number to the right side and vertical middle?

Comment: To the right side certainly, but what do you mean with ‘vertical middle’?