# Put Chapter number in a box on an odd page

Tags: boxes, chapterthumb

I am trying to put a chapter number in a box on the odd page. [Box with chapter number on each even page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398327/box-with-chapter-number-on-each-even-page) has been of great help. But I am trying to move the box on odd page. I tried several things but I couldn't succeed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[paperheight=24cm,paperwidth=17cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}

\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Adding box to the chapter
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}
\definecolor{chapterthumbbg}{HTML}{6F7170}
%\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
%  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
%    \ifshowchapterthumb\ifodd\value{page}
%      \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
%        \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}{%
%          \setlength{\fboxsep}{\baselineskip}%
%          \colorbox{chapterthumbbg}{\textcolor{white}{\begin{turn}{0}\textbf{{\LARGE \thechapter}}\end{turn}}}%
%        }%
%      }%
%    \fi\fi
%  }
%}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \ifshowchapterthumb%\ifodd\value{page} % <==========================
      \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}{%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{\baselineskip}%
          \colorbox{chapterthumbbg}{\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}%
        }%
      }%
    \fi%\fi % <=========================================================
  }
}

\newif\ifshowchapterthumb

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\newcommand*\chem[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{Eq. \arabic{equation}}



%\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}

%\titleclass{\chapter}{page}
%\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
%\titleformat{\chapter}
%    [display]
%    {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
%    { }
%    {0pt}
%    {\huge}
%    [\clearpage]



\begin{document}


%\showchapterthumbfalse
%
%\input{Frontmatter/Title}
%\pagebreak
%\input{Frontmatter/committe}
%\pagebreak
%\input{Frontmatter/official_title}
%\pagebreak
%\input{Frontmatter/approvedby}


\tableofcontents
%\newpage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\mbox{}

\part{Name 1}
\showchapterthumbtrue
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]
\showchapterthumbfalse

\part{Name 2}
\showchapterthumbtrue
\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]
\showchapterthumbfalse

%\include{Mainmatter/Chapter_1}
%%\newpage
%%\thispagestyle{empty}
%%\mbox{}
%\include{Mainmatter/Chapter_2}
%%\newpage
%%\thispagestyle{empty}
%%\mbox{}
%
%\part{Name}
%\include{Mainmatter/Chapter_3}



\end{document}
```

This code just works fine for even page. I would like to move the box on the odd page. Some inputs will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All you need to do (at least in the example you're referring to) is to move the `\else` from after `\value{page}` just before `\fi\fi`.

Comment: Would you have the box on the left side or the right side of odd pages?

Comment: If you want it on both, delete `\ifodd\value{page}\else` and one of the `\fi`s. If you want it only on odd, delete the `\else`.  Demonstration is impossible without a proper example, though.

Comment: @Bernard - i wanted to move chapter thumb to idd page from even page.

Comment: The problem, for me, is that such thumbnails should be in the outer margin, which means in the right margin for odd pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the construct

```
\ifodd\value{page} % is value of page odd then do
  % code to be executed for odd page
\else
  % code to be executed for even pages
\fi
```

you can define what has to be done.  I understand your question in the way, that you want the box **only** on odd pages.  So you need the code to be:

```
\ifodd\value{page}
      \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}{%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{\baselineskip}%
          \colorbox{chapterthumbbg}{\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}%
        }%
      }%
\fi
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}

\definecolor{chapterthumbbg}{HTML}{6F7175}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \ifshowchapterthumb\ifodd\value{page} % <=================================
      \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}{%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{\baselineskip}%
          \colorbox{chapterthumbbg}{\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}%
        }%
      }%
    \fi\fi
  }
}

\newif\ifshowchapterthumb

\sloppy% Just for this document

\begin{document}

\showchapterthumbfalse% Default

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\showchapterthumbtrue% Show chapter thumbs

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\end{document}
```

you get the box for chapter only on odd pages like:

If you want the box on even and odd pages just use (simply delete the lines containing `\ifodd` and `\fi`):

```
  \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}{%
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{\baselineskip}%
      \colorbox{chapterthumbbg}{\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}%
    }%
  }%
```

With the resulting MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}

\definecolor{chapterthumbbg}{HTML}{6F7175}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \ifshowchapterthumb%\ifodd\value{page} % <==========================
      \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}{%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{\baselineskip}%
          \colorbox{chapterthumbbg}{\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}%
        }%
      }%
    \fi%\fi % <=========================================================
  }
}

\newif\ifshowchapterthumb

\sloppy% Just for this document

\begin{document}

\showchapterthumbfalse% Default

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\showchapterthumbtrue% Show chapter thumbs

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\end{document}
```

you get even and odd pages with boxes:

[image]

[image: resulting odd page]

Comment: @pukumarathe  Please ask a new question for the two new problems. We like here to have one question with corresponding answers in one post.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have updated my question on following link. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404323/title-pages-for-chapters-and-chapter-thumbs