# Page numbering and chapter number together in chapter thumb

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, chapterthumb

I am trying to create a template for my PhD thesis. I liked the way Yo' has shown the page numbers in a box [ [Formatting page number (fancyhdr?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89666/formatting-page-number-fancyhdr) ]. I have tweaked his code little bit and to add the Chapter number and the page numbers. However, I have following **two** problems.

1. In my front matter I see the box with chapter number zero and roman number two, which is not desired. I would prefer to not to display any numbers (or box) until my first chapter begins.

[image]

2. As you can see in figure below that on the first page of the chapter, page number is displayed on the bottom of the page. I would like to display the box with chapter number and page number also next to the heading of the chapter.

[image]

Following is my code. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance. :)

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[paperheight=25cm,paperwidth=17.6cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage[a4, cam, center]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=8pt}
\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\newcommand*\chem[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{Eq. \arabic{equation}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\Huge\bfseries}{}{0cm}{}



%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\ooalign{%
\color{black!60!white}% background box color
\rule[0.05in]{0.7in}{1in}% background box raise, width, height
\cr
\hfil\strut\raisebox{0.25in}{% number raise
\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}% number color
\Huge% number fontsize
\thechapter
\kern0.1em% distance number-bar
\rule{1pt}{1.4ex}% bar size
\kern0.15em% distance bar-totalnumber
\large% totalnumber fontsize
\thepage}\hfil
}}}
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{0.8in}% protrusion 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\makeatother



\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{5cm}
    \line(1,0){250}\\
    \huge{Thesis Title}
    \line(1,0){250}\\
    \vspace*{5cm}
    {\Large Name}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Chapter 1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[1-10]


\chapter{Chapter 3}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Chapter 4}
\lipsum[1-10]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[paperheight=25cm,paperwidth=17.6cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage[a4, cam, center]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=8pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{lineno}
%\linenumbers
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\newcommand*\chem[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{Eq. \arabic{equation}}


%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% for remving all styles from front matter
\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
% for adding boxes with chapter and page numbers
\fancypagestyle{style2}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\ooalign{%
\color{black!60!white}% background box color
\rule[0.05in]{0.7in}{1in}% background box raise, width, height
\cr
\hfil\strut\raisebox{0.25in}{% number raise
\bfseries\color{white}% number color
\Huge% number fontsize
\thechapter
\kern0.1em% distance number-bar
\rule{1pt}{1.4ex}% bar size
\kern0.15em% distance bar-totalnumber
\large% totalnumber fontsize
\thepage}\hfil
}}}
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{0.8in}% protrusion 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{style2}}{}{}

\pagestyle{style1}

\begin{document}


%\begin{titlepage}
%\begin{center}
%   \vspace*{5cm}
%   \line(1,0){250}\\
%   \huge{Thesis Title}
%   \line(1,0){250}\\
%   \vspace*{5cm}
%   {\Large Name}
%\end{center}
%\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}



\chapter{Introduction}
\pagestyle{style2}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{1}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{2}\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Experimental}
\pagestyle{style2}
\lipsum[1-10]



\chapter{Chapter 3}
\pagestyle{style2}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Appendix 3A}

\chapter{Chapter 4}
\pagestyle{style2}
\lipsum[1-10]


\end{document}
```